# Low Disk Space on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

This is about my office computer (Windows 7) on which I want to install TeXmaker. I realised that I had not enough disk space for TeXMaker. However I thought it would be a good idea to uninstall MikTeX but it does not even have enough memory to uninstall a program. I tried changing virtual memory to some other drive which has almost two terrabytes of space but there is no option other than C: to select, for virtual memory. Since this is not a computer of my own, I cannot safely delete files from the root of the drive, namely C:.

I wrote to hive (the system admins here) for help and they haven't responded yet. There are two folders

```
Program files
Program files (x86)
```

I tried sending each one of these to the recycle bin with all folders closed. Still it said the action couldn't be completed because some file in the folder is open.

It would be great if someone could help, by some means, freeing up at least a gigabyte of space from C:, which is of capacity 74 GB approx and now has just a few KB of free space.

Comment: Open Windows Explorer and enter `%temp%` in the address/path bar. Delete everything in here, it's just temporary files which is ok to delete. Also check if you can delete old downloads or unused documents etc from your user folder; **C:\Users\yourUsername\ **

Comment: Wait for your IT staff.

Comment: @KEK Thanks! I would imagine this comment is an answer though it is pretty much common sense!

Comment: @Hold voters: When I checked a stackexchange site (meta.stackexchange if I recall correctly) and found that super user is a good place to ask windows questions. This was a response to a rather desperate suggestion by someone of having a stackexchange site devoted exclusively for Windows, just like there is for Apple, Ubuntu etc.
I would appreciate if a more suitable site is suggested for such questions as above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try downloading ccleaner portable edition. No installer so can run with any permissions, and then check that it is not going to delete something you may want to keep (the 'recent items' folder, for example) - then click 'clean'. Also try WinDirStat to examine the hard disk and then display the largest files in a bar chart format.  WinDirStat does have a portable edition too.

Portable editions require no admin rights or installation.

Comment: That worked! I first did as KEK said. Then there was enough free space to install CCleaner. Now I have a GB worth of free space! Hurray!

Answer (score 0):

If it's a work computer, it really depends on what you're allowed to do.  I'm assuming you're allowed to install/uninstall software that isn't work-related.  With an HD that size, I would say there's probably more than a little bit of space taken up by programs and files that you probably don't need.

First, I'd clean your temp folder (as KEK suggested in the comments).  You might also want to clear your browser cache.  However, these things may only free up a few hundred megs (at most), which may be enough, but you should probably free quite a bit more, if you can, as it will drastically improve performance.

The next thing I'd do is go into my downloads folder and check to make sure I don't have anything massive in there that I don't need (installers are pretty notorious for being HUGE files that are virtually pointless after they've been run for the first time, and often contribute quite a bit to "disk clutter").

The next thing I'd do is start uninstalling software I don't use anymore (for me, this is usually games I haven't played in quite some time).  If the software is smaller than 100MB, I wouldn't necessarily bother, as it will likely take too long for too little in extra space.  Start wit the bigger ones, first.  If you go into the control panel and select "uninstall programs," then click the "size" column header, you can sort them by the amount of disk space they (supposedly) take up.

After that, I'd go through my documents folders and desktop folders (assuming that everything up until this point didn't free up enough disk space) to make sure there are no massive files that aren't used by me or anything I use floating around (usually leftovers from an uninstalled program).

Video files and images can also take up quite a bit of space, if you have a lot of them.  You may want to consider moving those to a separate storage medium, like a flash drive, an external HD, or a few DVDs.